# Received memory warning in UICollectionView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, didreceivememorywarning

I am using UICollectionView to show all the images available in my library using assets, its displaying all the images but when I scroll up and down many times , I receive a memory issue in the device and after some time it gets crashed saying **CRASHED DUE TO MEMORY PRESSURE**
code used are as follows

creates here the collectionview and settings its delegate

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
allPhotosCollectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 481)collectionViewLayout:layout];
[allPhotosCollectionView setDelegate:self];
[allPhotosCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[allPhotosCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:allPhotosCollectionView];
```

delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [allImageArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:       (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
return CGSizeMake(95, 100);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
// allimageArray has the Assest URL fo the images
NSURL *aURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[allImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[assestLibrary assetForURL:aURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
 {
     UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImager = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
     UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
     NSData *imageData;
     imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(copyOfOriginalImager, 0.4);
     [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
  }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
  {
     // error handling
     NSLog(@"failure-----");
    }];
  return cell;
  }
```

I am facing many problems in iOS 7 , app crash due to memory pressure , please explain that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its due to assest library. Once u fetched the image using assest libary just store it in some variable and re-use that image in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

while scrolling the collection view it will fetch the image again and again using asset libary this will cause huge memory leak.

Edit:

```
 UIImage *img =[imageDictionary objectForKey:imageName];
                if(!img)
                {

                    NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageName];
                    img = [McAssetReader readImage:asseturl];
                    [imageDictionary setObject:img forKey:imageName];
                }
```

where **imageDictionary** is the **Global** Dictionay for holding the image.
**imageName** is the url for particular image.

Comment: you are telling me to store the images in arrays and then use it in cellForItemAtIndexPath  ?

Comment: Yes just keep track of images which is already read using asset library. If a images is not available in local variable then fetch it using asset library else use the image from local library.

Comment: @CoolMonster how can we store it if it has 1000+ images? Is it correct way do it?

Comment: @Mani, no, the correct way would be using `NSCache` of reasonable size and purge policy.

Comment: k. Why do we use NSCache here? He didn't hold memory anywhere? Where do you see as holding image? Just 10-15 cell keep alive at all time means, how get all images alive in this?

Comment: I accept one thing, if he fetch from asset means, it may struck because of loading from assets? It won't create memory issue if not holding or processing that image?

Comment: it will cause memory issue if u fetching the image again and again using asset library.the image allocated by the asset library not released until the viewController is released. u can use NSCache to cache and display the image. also don't show the original image in thumbnail u can fetch the thumbnail view from the asset library.

Comment: Your answer didn't clearly. I also ask about it. Where your view controller(cell has imageview to hold that image) hold that image which loaded from asset? or Are you saying about your VC must hold if you load image from asset?

Comment: @CoolMonster Hey man, I can understand of your Cache concept? My question, why we need cache in this place?

Comment: @Mani i think u never understand the problem of using the asset library, u jus talking the views he used. u r right add imageview again and again cause memory waste but its not an big issue, u try the way u said just just scroll the collection view or tableview again again u applicaiton will get crash.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44397/discussion-between-mani-and-coolmonster)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

- You're keep adding imageViews to cell without even checking if one already exist, hence memory usage is growing rapidly;
- You're not caching results of your image transformation and keep reading/transforming on every cell dequeue, hence you're keep pressure on disk IO and memory;

Cache and reuse technics will most likely fix your problems.

Comment: When collection cell gets reload, all cells going to dealloc and should alive only below than 10-15 cells? then how it will crash due to `keep adding imageViews`? Please would you please explain more in details? Because he doesn't hold image memory anywhere?

Comment: Quoting from UICollectionView docs: `If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.`; so these imageViews just keeps stacking on top of each other until cell will be deallocated.

Comment: would you please refer this document with appropriate topic? Is it all cell alive when scrolling? Are you try to mention this point or other tech points?

Comment: see my answer. Your answer will also help him lot. But not for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I can see issue here. Surely It will lead to memory error.

```
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
.
.
.    
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

See this line. You are creating imageView everytime and holding that image into imageview.

So you can do this instead of first line.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ImageViewTag];
if (!imageView)
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}
```